# App crash help me understand my device crash log

Tags: ios, sigabrt

I maintain an app for Enterprise Distribution and I've recently made some changes to the app. The changes appear to work fine. When I push the new build to a connected device the app works fine. If I download the app from the install location it installs fine but crashes on launch.

I package the app the normal way via the archive utility > Export > select Enterprise Distribution option and select the only profile in the list (which is current)

After I have the .ipa I change the extension to .zip and extract the 'Applications' folder and change name to 'Payload' then I re-zip and change extension back to .ipa. Without this step the app doesn't even load and this has worked in the past.

I have a crash log of which doesn't seem that intuitive and am looking for some direction in terms of interpretation (posted up to binary images).

Crash log:

```
Incident Identifier: E133FB64-75DD-48FD-AE94-30130139A1ED
CrashReporter Key:   bd52084c1995dae3f3d8a36ba35cad6e781f1c7a
Hardware Model:      iPad2,5
Process:             AMS Mobile [481]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/C99B11DF-2A57-4BA1-91EE-1D9A792841A3/AMS Mobile.app/AMS Mobile
Identifier:          com.mobile.ams
Version:             1 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-08-14 09:28:36.881 -0500
Launch Time:         2015-08-14 09:28:36.447 -0500
OS Version:          iOS 8.4 (12H143)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x245c5132 __exceptionPreprocess + 122
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32d40c72 objc_exception_throw + 34
2   CoreFoundation                  0x245c5078 +[NSException raise:format:] + 108
3   UIKit                           0x27ff6424 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 852
4   UIKit                           0x27ff7f3a -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 158
5   UIKit                           0x27e8a63a -[UIApplication _loadMainNibFileNamed:bundle:] + 30
6   UIKit                           0x27e899cc -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1148
7   UIKit                           0x27e947a4 __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 32
8   UIKit                           0x27e88282 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 126
9   FrontBoardServices              0x2b06eebc __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke_2 + 12
10  CoreFoundation                  0x2458b250 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 8
11  CoreFoundation                  0x2458a514 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 212
12  CoreFoundation                  0x24588cb2 __CFRunLoopRun + 754
13  CoreFoundation                  0x244d499c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
14  CoreFoundation                  0x244d47ae CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
15  UIKit                           0x27c8aa52 -[UIApplication _run] + 554
16  UIKit                           0x27c85630 UIApplicationMain + 1436
17  AMS Mobile                      0x000ce3ee main (main.m:14)
18  libdyld.dylib                   0x3330eaaa tlv_initializer + 2


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x333d4df0 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x33455c92 pthread_kill + 58
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33373934 abort + 72
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3254cbb8 abort_message + 84
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3256666a default_terminate_handler() + 262
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32d40f0e _objc_terminate() + 190
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x32563dec std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 76
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x325638b4 __cxa_rethrow + 96
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32d40dba objc_exception_rethrow + 38
9   CoreFoundation                  0x244d4a38 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 628
10  CoreFoundation                  0x244d47ae CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
11  UIKit                           0x27c8aa52 -[UIApplication _run] + 554
12  UIKit                           0x27c85630 UIApplicationMain + 1436
13  AMS Mobile                      0x000ce3ee main (main.m:14)
14  libdyld.dylib                   0x3330eaac start + 0

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x333c124c kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x332e14ec _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 276
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x332e121e _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$mp + 34

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x333d59c0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x33452e20 _pthread_wqthread + 788
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x33452af8 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3 name:  Dispatch queue: FBSSerialQueue
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x333c14ec semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x332deb8e _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 186
2   FrontBoardServices              0x2b06ee9e __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 142
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x332d0c80 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x332db4ce _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$mp + 1458
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x332dad9c _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 80
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x332dd48e _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 386
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x332de89e _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 102
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x33452da6 _pthread_wqthread + 666
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x33452af8 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x333d59c0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x33452e20 _pthread_wqthread + 788
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x33452af8 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x333d59c0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x33452e20 _pthread_wqthread + 788
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x33452af8 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00000003
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x35d429dc      r6: 0x35d2e840      r7: 0x001fc418
    r8: 0x146602c0    r9: 0x7420666f     r10: 0x35d2d074     r11: 0x146602e4
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x001fc40c      lr: 0x33455c97      pc: 0x333d4df0
  cpsr: 0x00000010
```

Comment: From what I can tell by using break points is my AppDelegate is never being called.

Comment: So I've made a little progress. I went into the main.m and explicitly called my appDelegate. This does run the code in 'application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions' but I am still left with a black screen.

Answer (score 0):

Info from crash report:

The line that seem most helpful is:
`3 UIKit 0x27ff6424 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 852`

This indicates the error is instantiating a nib.

Prior to that i the trace see:
`loadMainNibFileNamed`
So it i probably the main nib that can't be loaded.

Comment: So I've made a little progress. I went into the main.m and explicitly called my appDelegate. This does run the code in 'application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions' but I am still left with a black screen. One of the changes I made was adding the main nib to a uivavigationcontroller. in turn that is added to a tabbarcontroller.

Comment: Main shjould have the Apple standard code, no more,no less: `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`

`int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {`
   `int retVal;`
    `@autoreleasepool {`
        `retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);`
    `}`    
    `return retVal;`
`}`

Comment: When I do that 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions' never gets scope and I still have black screen. Thank you for your btw....